# LibreOffice shows previews of recently edited files on startup, how to disable this

Tags: libreoffice

I use LibreOffice 6.0.7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04. When I start LibreOffice from the command-line it displays previews of recently edited files. How can I switch this off? I prefer privacy over comfort and do not want MRU file lists, even less MRU file screenshots on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/143938/how-do-i-disable-recent-document-saving/): Menu Tools > Options > Libreoffice > Advanced > <kbd>Open Expert Configuration</kbd>. Type picklistsize and search button. The default value seems to be 25 (files in the picklist). Setting it to 0 should do the trick.